# Visibility of math formula in rmarkdown after knitting

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to create an R Markdown file and include a formula. The problem is that when I knit the document the formula appears as I have entered in a latex style.

```
---
output: github_document
---

$$P(E|L) = \frac{P(L|E) * P(E)}{P(L)} = \frac{0.3 * 0.5}{0.3 * 0.5 + 0.5*1} = 0.23$$
```

So when I knit it, it looks like:

[image: looks like]

where as in the code it appears.
[image]

What should I do so that when I knit the document, the formula looks like in the second picture?

Comment: Hi Gery, can you provide a full minimal example of your R Markdown document? It is likely that this issue is being caused by something else in the document. Something [like this](https://gist.github.com/dr-harper/0bf43bd8f53aa098e5b10c43e0db8a91)

Comment: Hi Michael, I have added the full code of the document in github. Thank you for the responce!

Comment: I added the code to the question. Sorry didn't mean to confuse you but I only used GitHub as an example script. Hope the answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from your use of the output format `github_document`. The github output format cannot directly support the maths mode. As stated by the **rmarkdown** package author in [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/806#issuecomment-326620465):

> I'd say that if you really care about LaTeX math in Markdown, you should render to HTML output instead of waiting indefinitely for Github to support MathJax in Markdown, which I doubt will ever happen.

Implementing his advice, we can change the output format to `html_document`:

```
---
output: html_document
---

$$
P(E|L) = \frac{P(L|E) * P(E)}{P(L)} = \frac{0.3 * 0.5}{0.3 * 0.5 + 0.5*1} = 0.23
$$
```

[image]